# How can I bypass my DNS provider's cache?

Tags: dns

I just changed the DNS settings on my website, which I use mainly for local testing. Unfortunately, I had the TTL of the old settings at a day or, so and I don't want to wait for it to update. Is there any way to fetch the latest dns settings even though my DNS provider (Google DNS) has it cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different DNS provider, like OpenDNS.  If the website is popular enough other providers may also have the DNS cached so keep trying others.

Also if you are using Windows clear your local cache in a command prompt type `ipconfig /flushdns` a few times.  Also close your browser/clear cache all that good stuff.

Answer (score 8):

The best way is to query your domain's *authoritative* server directly -

```
nslookup yourdomain.com nameserver.for.your.domain.com
```

If you don't know which name server is authoritative for your domain, find it -

```
nslookup

> set q=NS
> yourdomain.com
```

It will list addresses of all namservers which your domain uses, and then to query it directly, you pass any of them as second parameter to your `nslookup`